# Selenium WedDriver - Multiple Java Class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

New To Selenium

I have a base class, which will initiate `webdriver`. Following pages are available for creating a contract.

Login-> Select Plan-> Add Premises-> add details

```
    public class BaseClass {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public WebDriverWait wait;

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    @BeforeClass(description = "Class Level Setup!")
    public void setup() {
        // Create a Chrome driver. All test classes use this.
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Selenium/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        // Create a wait. All test classes use this.
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);

        // Maximize Window
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

}
```

And Login.Test

```
    public class LoginTest extends BaseClass {

 @Test(priority = 0, description="This TC is for Senoko login")
  void validateLogin() {
      driver.get("https://url domain/index"); 

      WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("userid_txt"));   
      WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("password_txt"));
      WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("submitBtn"));
      email.sendKeys("a01");
      password.sendKeys("test123");
      login.click();
      HouseholdCheck house=new HouseholdCheck();
      house.houseCheck();
  } 

}
```

Up to this point working.  In the `validateLogin()` method, calling `houseCheck` method , Here I am getting `NullPointerException`.

```
  public class HouseholdCheck extends BaseClass {

@Test
void houseCheck() {
    System.out.println("=====" + driver);
    driver.get("https://a-sit.aspx?source=CSP&key=1");
    WebElement radio1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='resbiz' and @value='households']"));
    WebElement radio2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='resbiz' and @value='business']"));
    radio1.click();
    WebElement radbutton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Continue')]"));
    radbutton.click();
    PlanSelect plnslct = new PlanSelect();
    plnslct.planSelect(driver);
}
```

}

In the `HouseholdCheck` class, not able to access `driver`. Giving `NullPointerException`. Please guide me, how to pass driver to subsequent classes? If a class extends `BaseClass`, why that class can't get driver object?

Comment: i would suggest to use any of the framework which provides driver management and other functional testing needs. One of the open source framework you can try is [qaf](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/). Refer [qaf-step-by-step-tutorial](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-step-by-step-tutorial/wiki)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `HouseholdCheck house = new HouseholdCheck();` you create new instance of `BaseClass`, where the `driver` was never initialized. You call `houseCheck()` as method and not run it as test so the `setup()` is not being executed.

One solution is to make the `driver` static

```
private static WebDriver driver;

public static WebDriver getDriver() {
    return driver;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class BaseClass {
    public static WebDriver driver;
```

Just make this static and you are good to go.